# Exploding drop down values

Tags: php

I posted a question about this earlier but now i have a new problem that I dont get. 
Here is the HTML:

```
 <select name="contactname">
 <option></option>
 <option value="John Smith|Jsmith@email.com">John Smith</option>
 </select>
```

Here is the error i get now that i made the changes on the Posting page. 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING on line 48

Here is the Posting Page:

```
</head>
<body>

<?php

$pickone = $_POST [pickone];
$dropone = $_POST [dropone];
$weight = $_POST [weight];
$length = $_POST [length];
$pallets = $_POST [pallets];
$pickupdate = $_POST [pickupdate];
$equipment = $_POST [equipment];
$loadtype = $_POST [loadtype];
$specialinformation = $_POST [specialinformation];
$commodity = $_POST [commodity];
$closetime = $_POST [closetime];
$deliverydate = $_POST [deliverydate];
$req = $_POST [req];
$contact = explode('|', $_POST[contactname]);


$header = "From: " . $contact[0] . " <" . $contact[1] . ">\r\n"; 
$subject= "New Load";
$from= "You";

$message = " 
Picks: $pickone
Drops: $dropone \n   
  PU Date: $pickupdate     Close Time: $closetime
 Del Date: $deliverydate \n
     Mode: $loadtype
Equipment: $equipment
   Length: $length
   Weight: $weight
  Pallets: $pallets
Commodity: $commodity \n

Requirements:
$req \n
Special Information: $specialinformation
Contact: $contactname[0]
";

mail("email.com", $subject, $message, $header");

?>

<p align="center">Thank You<br>
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='page.php';" value=" Post Another Load    " />
</p> 

</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know what I'm missing because if i dont try to explode contactname it works fine. Thanks,

Comment: No offense, but your code is really bad. Please add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the beginning of your code and then fix all the notices. Mainly quoting strings (your array keys) - i.e. `$_POST['pickone']` instead of `$_POST [pickone]`

Answer (score 1):

```
mail("email.com", $subject, $message, $header");
```

Remove the quote at the end:

```
mail("email.com", $subject, $message, $header);
```

Additionally you really want to insert a real email address instead of "email.com"

While fixing stuff, also quote all your array keys - i.e. `$_POST['something']` instead of `$_POST[something]` and enable notices using `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the one line read:

```
Contact: $contact[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of mail, you have an extra double quote
`mail("email.com", $subject, $message, $header");`
should be
`mail("email.com", $subject, $message, $header);`

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an errant " at the end of the mail line.

Try changing it to: `mail("email.com",$subject,$message,$header);`

Other than that I don't see much wrong with it